# Why does Excel display these CSV files differently? One with Quotes One Without

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have two csv files and they appear the same when I look at them in a text editor like notepad++.  However, when I open them both in Excel (2003 at this moment) one of them shows double quotes in fields and the other does not.  Does anyone know why this is the case?

Note: The columns are in different orders and have different number of them

**File 1 shows " in excel**

```
"1794", "FEMALE", "9", "", "CHRISTENSEN", "JAMES FAKE", "LUCIA", "8/28/2006", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "40890", "209417", "767-544-033", ""
```

**File 2 does not show " in excel**

```
"1794","CHRISTENSEN","JAMES FAKE","LUCIA","8/28/2006","9","FEMALE","","","","","","",""
```

What other offending variables should I look for?  Does encoding matter?

Comment: not considering the order both looks the same for me, values are surrounded by " in both lines

Comment: The first file has spaces following the commas.

Comment: I suspect encoding...

Comment: According to RFC 4180, spaces outside quotes in a field are not allowed; however, the RFC also says that "Spaces are considered part of a field and should not be ignored." and "Implementors should 'be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others' (RFC 793 [8]) when processing CSV files."

Comment: In some CSV implementations, leading and trailing spaces and tabs are trimmed (ignored). Such trimming is forbidden by RFC 4180, which states "Spaces are considered part of a field and should not be ignored."

Comment: Removing the space after each Comma did the trick.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### One of them shows double quotes in fields and the other does not

> Does anyone know why this is the case?

The first file has spaces following the commas.

Remove the spaces to get the same behaviour with both files.

> According to RFC 4180, spaces outside quotes in a field are not
>   allowed; however, the RFC also says that "Spaces are considered part
>   of a field and should not be ignored." and "Implementors should 'be
>   conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from
>   others' (RFC 793) when processing CSV files.
>
> ```
> 1997, Ford, E350
> ```
>
> is not same as
>
> ```
> 1997,Ford,E350
> ```

Source [Comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

Comment: I believe that the quoted Wikipedia article is wrong. It was introduced [in this change](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Comma-separated_values&type=revision&diff=592965137&oldid=592554922). I explain it in why it is wrong in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492244/is-whitespace-at-the-end-of-a-line-valid-csv#comment62645138_22514146). Please ping me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As the OP commented above, removing the spaces solves the problem but if you don't want to manipulate the file before import, simply mark both Comma and Space as delimiters and check the "Treat consecutive delimiters as one" checkbox in the Text Import Wizard.

[image]